# Inserting Vlookup formula with for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really sure that I'm not doing it right but what I'm trying to do is insert a vlookup formula with a for loop function.

```
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

cnt = [A:A].Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For row = 1 To cnt
col = col + 1
[A2].Offset(row - 1, 1).Value = "Vlookup(A" & col + 1 & ",'Sheet1'!,A$2:A$" & cnt & ",1,0)"
Next row
```

The `VLOOKUP` formula's `lookup_value` should be same with `col + 1` and `col_index_num` would be equal to `cnt`

I tried the `.Value` option but it's not accepting it as since it has a `"="` on the string. I tried using the `.Formula` function but it's not giving me an option to insert `col + 1` on it as well as `cnt.`

Comment: is this code in a sheet module or a code module?

Comment: Code module. Module 1. But since you've mentioned it, I tried to put on the sheet module and it worked. Maybe I just need to learn how to do it in a code module instead of a sheet module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rogue comma in this line

```
[A2].Offset(row - 1, 1).Value = "Vlookup(A" & col + 1 & ",'Sheet1'!,A$2:A$" & cnt & ",1,0)"
```

There should not be a comma after `'Sheet1'!`. Remove it.

Edit: You need to start a formula with a `=` sign, even when it is entered in VBA.

```
This code runs fine in my tests:

Sub test()
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Long

cnt = [A:A].Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For row = 1 To cnt
col = col + 1
[A2].Offset(row - 1, 1).Value = "=Vlookup(A" & col + 1 & ",'Sheet1'!A$2:A$" & cnt & ",1,0)"
Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've removed it but still I'm getting an error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: I added a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `table_array` is supposed to be. But something like this should work:

```
[a2].Offset(row - 1, 1).Value = "=Vlookup(A" & col + 1 & ",'Sheet1'!A$2," & cnt & ",0)"
```

Comment: I've tried this but the error I'm getting is with the "=" on the .Value function.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly catched your goal, you can avoid looping and use ".FormulaR1C1" property of "Range" object to take advantage of relative range referencing, like follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cnt As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<--| this is the sheet where to lookup
        cnt = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("MySheet") '<--| change "MySheet" with your actual "working" sheet name
        .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-1], 'Sheet1'!A$2:A$" & cnt & ",1,0)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Marco: did you try this?